# Implementing a custom UISwitch using a library - what am I doing wrong that's causing the size issues?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiswitch

I'm using [BMXSwitch](https://github.com/mbigatti/BMXSwitch) to implement a custom UISlider, hopefully in the end looking something like this:

[image]

Where the animation is pretty much identical to the default UISwitch, where the knob moves, pulling the whole view over as well, and resting on the other side with the other option visible.

However, using that library (and messing around with the example included), the closest I can get to that is the following:

[image]

[Here's a download link to my project if it would help.](http://cl.ly/2g3B1D1w2Q3S)

Here's the code I customized to do that:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [_switch1 setCanvasImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"canvas-custom"]];
    [_switch1 setMaskImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"mask-custom"]];

    [_switch1 setKnobImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"slider-knob-custom"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [_switch1 setKnobImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"slider-knob-custom"] forState: UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [_switch1 setKnobImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"slider-knob-custom"] forState: UIControlStateDisabled];

    [_switch1 setContentImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"slider-background-custom"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [_switch1 setContentImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"slider-background-custom"] forState: UIControlStateDisabled];

    [self valueChanged: nil];
//    _switch1.on = YES;
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I have a feeling it's just with image sizes (the images are included with that download link), so if you can just suggest to me the sizing I'd need, or whatever I need to do to fix this, I'd really appreciate the help, it's stumping me greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is inside the .xib. You have defined a BMXSwitch with a large frame. The frame of the switch must be equal to the size of your button, no more.

[image]

Comment: Fair enough, thank you. But I'm still having the issue with the knob being out of alignment. How would I fix that?

Comment: Your images are not good (they are too tiny for the entire switch).